# Laravel route with where clause

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel and Vue.js to create a wizard form with multiple steps. However, I'm having difficulty configuring the third segment of my route to match any URL after "shipping-address-sender?/*". Specifically, I want the route to match any URL that comes after "shipping-address-sender?/*" with a wildcard character.

But i am getting 404 if i try to access this url `address-sender/manual` or `address-receiver/manual`

````
           ->get('{step?}', [StepController::class, 'show'])
           ->where('step', 'address-sender?/*|address-receiver?/*|shipping-confirmation')
           ->name('auth.step.show');```
````

Comment: everything after `?` is a query string and routing isn't based on query strings (it isn't considered part of the path for routing)

Comment: Thank you for your response. What would be the most effective method to achieve my desired outcome?

Comment: you perhaps could be using 2 wild cards with one being optional ... `get('{step}/{rest?}', ...)` then you would have 2 wheres, the one for `step` would be checking the 3 possibilities and the one for `rest` would be the catchall (`'.*'`)